# make a listing function for a array Jquery / Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

so..

```
var songList = ["1", "2" ,"3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10"];
```

so my idea is to make a function which returns the first 5 Set of the values according to the index.
if

```
getList("1"); // is called.
```

it should result in "1 2 3 4 5" output.
and if 
   getList("2"); // is called
it should result in " 6 7 8 9 10"

Comment: Your question is unclear. Do you want to make a list that looks like your songList example? Or do you mean that you want makeList to return the 5 next songs from songList at the index provided?

Comment: Nono. i want it to return next 5 songs from songList at the index provided.

Comment: Perhaps you should edit your question to clarify it.

Comment: [arr.slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) should do

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you need something like this:

```
var songList = ["01R!Wagner=_W!_March.mid ", "1004. score.mid ", "1005. yanni-one mans dream.mid ", "1006. haggstrom.mid ", "1007. la campanella pi.mid ", "1008. chp op18.mid ", "1009. Avicii - Wake Me Up.mid ", "101. Titanic my-heart will go on.mid ", "1010. 3intro.mid ", "1011. cast int.mid ", "1012. Action52Cheetahmen.mid ", "1013. pinkband.mid ", "1014. goldendreams.mid ", "1015. Reflections Of A Passion (Yanni).mid ", "1016. Nostalgia (Yanni).mid ", "1017. Rozen Maiden - Kinjirareta Asobi.mid ", "1018. Triple baka.mid ", "102. Konduktor.mid ", "1020. kraftwerk-franz schubert.mid ", "1021. naruto shippuuden - Blue Bird.mid ", "1022. naruto shippuuden - DIVER.mid ", "1023. dire-dire-docks-arranged-.mid ", "1024. koopa-s-theme.mid ", "1025. theme.mid ", "1026. the-last-spartan.mid ", "1027. xbox-startup-sequence.mid ", "1028. sml1-1.mid ", "1029. fourside1.mid ", "103. Minecraft - Sweden.mid ", "1030. eb hotel.mid ", "1031. smoke.mid ", "1032. whoboss.mid ", "1033. entrtanr.mid ", "1034. Eiffel 65- I'm blue (dabadee).mid "];

function makeList(index) {
    var start = Math.max(0, (index-1)*5), // to avoid negative indexes
        end = Math.min(index*5, songList.length); // to avoid out-of-bound

    return songList.slice(start, end);
}
```

Comment: the fiddle now returns the same array. however this is a cleaner solution, thanks to .slice (:

Answer (score 1):

How about this

```
var songList = ["song_1.mp3","song_2.mp3",
                "song_3.mp3","song_4.mp3",
                "song_5.mp3","song_6.mp3",
                "song_7.mp3","song_8.mp3"]

function makeList(index){
    var songsLength = songList.length;
    var num_songs = (index+5);
    var next_songs = [];

    if (num_songs > songsLength){
        console.log("cant select index that is greater than length");
    } else {
        for(var i = index; i < num_songs;i++ ){
            next_songs.push(songList[i]);
        }
        return next_songs;
    }
}
```

You can pass any index to start from your list. with `num_songs` you can change how many songs you want to return. Remember that the index starts at 0, so if you want to be able to pass makeList(1) to return the first element, you could also set `for (var i = (index-1); i < songsLength; i++)`

`makeList(3)` will return the same as `songList.slice(3, 8)`

Check the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zz5kj9bg/4/)

Comment: thats but that isn't my idea.. it should exclude the first 5 or according to when getList("2"); or more is called, but thanks anyway for helping!

Comment: to clarify it should Chop off 5 values from the beginning according to the index so if index is 1 it will get the first 5 and if it is 2 it will leave the First 5 and trim off the Next 5.. oh i think i am making this more confusing.

Comment: I do not understand. makeList("2") will return `songList[2] - songList[7]` and therefore exclude the prepending indeces. 
[here is a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zz5kj9bg/2/)

Comment: From what you write, this is what `makeList(index)` does (: